# Is localStorage considered a cookie by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, session-storage

I am making a small HTML page with Javascript. It won't need a server side, but i need store what the person have done, so i am using localStorage.(A checklist)

Now a days browsers have the option to do not store cookies, and sites warns the user if they use cookies or not.

So my questions are:

1:I need to warn the user that data is being stored, but just in the client side?

2:Browsers considers localStorage and sessionSotrage a kind of a cookie? I mean, do not save the data when the user select to always erase the cookies or consider it a kind of a threat.

Comment: Cookies are cookies, localStorage is localStorage.

Comment: Interesting question from that viewpoint.  I wonder how long it will be before the EU cottons on and we'll end up with a new law forcing us to warn that our websites are storing data on user's devices in this fashion too.

Comment: Is your question about the cookie law ?

Comment: I didn't know there was a law for cookies. I mean, cookie storage things in client side, localStorage store things in client side. Media say that cookies will track you, people got crazy and block cookies and site data. And this way my app will not work.

Comment: @ahwelp I just tested and the WebDevelopperTool plugin that can 'Disable Cookie' also block storage data..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to warn the user that data is being stored, but just in the client side?

It depends on the specific legislation that you are concerned about. In the UK, for instance, the wording of [*The Privacy and Electronic Communications (EC Directive) Regulations 2003*](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2003/2426/regulation/6/made) says:

> > , a person shall not use an electronic communications network to store information, or to gain access to information stored, in the terminal equipment of a subscriber or user unless the requirements of paragraph (2) are met.

While it is commonly referred to as "The Cookie Law", it definitely does not apply solely to cookies.

---

> Browsers considers localStorage and sessionSotrage a kind of a cookie?

No

> I mean, do not save the data when the user select to always erase the cookies

When erasing them, Chrome bundles local storage with cookies. Doing a comprehensive investigation into all the circumstances where all browsers allow the user to determine when cookies and local storage will be erased is a bit beyond the typical scope of a SO question though.

[image: Chrome preferences]